# SP2010 - Productivity Hub - Missing Pages

Tags: list, pages, productivity

I had a brain-freeze and deleted my productivity hub pages list.  Does anyone have a copy of these files?  They are listed under the productivity hub site collection in the pages list.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Myself - reviewed sample site to recreate the pages. Trivial to do really.